# setting documentroot in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, documentroot

i've set the documentroot in httpd.conf as:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\user1\Documents\WebProjects"
```

if the files are located in WebProjects, they work; however if i create a sub folder [project] in WebProjects and access them via the browser, it doesn't load. for example, if i create a folder '**test**' in WebProjects and a php file called **test.php** and call it: `localhost/test/test.php` . .this won't work and give the error of file not found on server.

but if i put all the files in WebProjects itself, ie. test.php in WebProjects, it will work [`localhost/test.php`]. this makes my WebProjects folder look very cluttered with different files of different projects strewn around. and it isn't practical either.

i'm new to using apache and hence would like to know how to set the document root such that i can access and load all the Projects/folders in WebProjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

1. Check the Windows permissions on the
   "test" folder - my guess would be
   that the account that Apache is
   running as doesn't have read
   permission on the folder (and so
   can't see the PHP files inside it).
   You could also try looking at the
   permissions on the "WebProjects"
   folder - somewhere in the Advanced
   options there should be a way to
   force the permissions to apply to
   "child objects" - i.e. files/folders
   inside WebProjects.
2. Check the Apache error log to see if
   it gives a reason why it cannot find
   the file. You could also try
   changing the error logging level -
   look for the LogLevel directive in
   the config file - default is "warn",
   but "info" or "debug" will give more
   information.